Future requests, enable Agent in forked Repl
I would like to enable the Agent on forked Repl, now I only get the Assistant. Why?
I also would like to have the Agent in mobile version. I only notice this sometimes, but I am sure that you will be able to fix it. When can it be fixed?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
